# javascript arranges text differnt everytime I refresh IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a script that makes some text slide depending on the title. However every time I refresh the page in IE the page titles switch order. It works fine in Firefox. I made a jsbin with the relevant code.

http://jsbin.com/ihopoq/1/

Comment: I have tracked the problem down to the line 'menu.wrap('<a href="#"></a>').parent().appendTo(submenu);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the line:

```
menu.wrap('<a href="#"></a>').parent().appendTo(submenu);
```

with

```
menu = menu.wrap('<a href="#"></a>');              
menu.each(function( index ) {
  $(this).parent().appendTo(submenu);
});
```

I think the parent function does not maintain the order of the elements in IE.

Comment: You should accept your answer if it solved the problem.

Comment: It says I can accept it in 23 hours. I would love to accept it now